# Android Studio Gradle proxy settings

Tags: android, http, android-studio, gradle

I get an error while compiling project:

Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
>   Could not resolve de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.2.1.
>        Required by:
>            MyApp:app:unspecified
>   Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/de/hdodenhof/circleimageview/1.2.1/circleimageview-1.2.1.pom'. Received status code 407 from server: authenticationrequired

I set proxy settings

```
-Dhttp.proxyHost=proxy.domain.company.com -Dhttp.proxyPort=8090 -Dhttp.proxyUser=atiris -Dhttp.proxyPassword=mysecretpassword
```

But it didn't helped. Also I set `http proxy settings` i Android Studio.Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0' call in your build.gradle ?

Comment: Yes, but 1.2.1 version.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to use a proxy for **a particular project**, go to your project directory and locate “**gradle.properties**” file. It should be in the same directory as “**build.gradle**” file. If you don’t see one, create one. Make sure to create “*gradle.properties*” and not “*gradle.properties.txt*”.

Add your proxy info-

> systemProp.http.proxyHost=some-proxy-host.com
>
> systemProp.http.proxyPort=some-port
>
> systemProp.https.proxyHost=some-proxy-host.com
>
> systemProp.https.proxyPort= some-port

If you have authentication as well, add-

> systemProp.http.proxyUser=userid
>
> systemProp.http.proxyPassword=password
>
> systemProp.https.proxyUser=userid
>
> systemProp.https.proxyPassword=password

If you want **all projects** to have the same proxy setting-

Go to your user home directory. In Win 7, it would be “*C:\Users\username*”. Locate **.gradle** directory and drop “**gradle.properties**” file you created above in **.gradle** directory.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the document. I hope this would help:
https://developer.android.com/tools/studio/studio-config.html#proxy