# NativeScript on windows: Vanilla build of sample project failed

Tags: android, windows, gradle, nativescript

I am starting with hello world example to learn nativescript.
I am compiling and building code behind corporate explicit proxy. I am able to create project and add android platform in my project. but when i try to build the project I face below error.

> D:\CurrentProjects\Android\NativeScript\simple>tns run android
>   Executing before-prepare hook from D:\CurrentProjects\Android\NativeScript\simpl
>   e\hooks\before-prepare\nativescript-dev-android-snapshot.js
>   Preparing project...
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>     A problem occurred configuring root project 'simple'.
>
>   > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
>   >     Could not download gradle-core.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:2.1
>   >     .2)
>   >     Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/bu
>   >     ild/gradle-core/2.1.2/gradle-core-2.1.2.jar'.
>   >     Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gr
>   >     adle-core/2.1.2/gradle-core-2.1.2.jar'.
>   >     This is usually a temporary error during hostname resolution and m
>   >     eans that the local server did not receive a response from an authoritative serv
>   >     er (jcenter.bintray.com)
> - Try:
>     Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
>     option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED
>
> Total time: 21.159 secs
>   Processing node_modules failed. Error: Command D:\CurrentProjects\Android\Native
>   Script\simple\platforms\android\gradlew.bat failed with exit code 1

[Gradle](https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle-core/2.1.2/gradle-core-2.1.2.jar) is accessible from browser. But "tns build android" or "tns run android" couldn't download and give above proxy error. This seems gradle error but don't have answer in gradle as well.

UPDATE: when network guy removed proxy authentication check at his end, gradle compiled. I guess issue is gradle is not taking up proxy settings as mentioned in other answers on stackoverflow.

Comment: Do you have "install permissions" on that work PC?

Comment: noticed in the error log: This is usually a temporary error during hostname resolution and means that the local server did not receive a response from an authoritative server ...

Comment: @Vladimir , Yes. I have administrative privileges on  work PC.. I am doing all installations .

Comment: @NickIliev , I could able to download gradle-core-2.1.2.jar in browser. So I don't think so its request time out kind of error. Its like Gradlewrapper couldn't pick up username password required for proxy to authenticate download.

Comment: Found the answer on this page.. [http://stackoverflow.com/a/32344111/3354591](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32344111/3354591)